# How redirect user if error.status == 401?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, axios, http-status-code-401

My goal is to redirect users if the code of request is equal to 401. I wrote follow code but it display me error 401. It displays me 401 (from console.log but below error). How can I implement redirection, if the error is equal to 401?

```
import axiosConfig from "../../config/axios";
import actions from "./actions";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
const fetchUser = async () => {
    const response = await axiosConfig.get('api/get-user')
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.response.status) // 401
            console.log(error.response.data.error) //Please Authenticate or whatever returned from server
            if (error.response.status == 401) {
                return(
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: '/login',
                            state: { from: location },
                        }}
                    />
                );
            }
        });
    return response.data
}
export const getUser = () =>
    async (dispatch) => {
        const user = await fetchUser()
       dispatch(actions.setUser(user));
    }
```

@Update
Routing setup

```
const Container = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
                            <Router>
                                <Switch>
                                    <Route path="/login">
                                        <Login />
                                    </Route>
                                    <Route path="/register">
                                        <Login />
                                    </Route>
                                        <Route path="/all-users">
                                            <Alltasks />
                                        </Route>
                                        <Route path="/all-articles">
                                            <AllUsers />
                                        </Route>
                                </Switch>
                            </Router>
                            <ToastContainer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You'll need to access the `history` object and invoke an imperative redirect, i.e. `history.replace`. Can you share your main router setup? Can you also share where and how `fetchUser` is called?

Comment: fetchUser is called in the above code. If I thought about getUser function, see that it's code to Redux. So Containercontroller (where it's Routing) I use it in  mapDispatchToProps and useEffect(). I updated my post

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that now, thanks. Can you share how you setup your `Router`, I suspect you'll need to either pass the `history` object to the `getUser` action creator or make a global, importable `history` object.

Comment: Look at mu code

Answer (score 3):

You can't return a `Redirect` component from an action, utility, or callback like this and expect it to be rendered and effect a redirect to a new route. Your option is to access the `history` object and invoke an imperative redirect.

### Option 1

Connect your router to redux with [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router). The basic gist is to create a custom "createRootReducer" function, create a `history` object, use the "ConnectedRouter" component. This allows you to dispatch redux actions to effect navigation actions in your app.

Follow the steps to setup and connect routing to your redux store.

To use in your asynchronous action:

```
import { replace } from 'connected-react-router';

...

const fetchUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosConfig.get('api/get-user');
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status == 401) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
}

export const getUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const user = await fetchUser();
    dispatch(actions.setUser(user));
  } catch {
    dispatch(replace('/login'));
  }
}
```

### Option 2

Create a history object and import and use in `getUser` action.

Create a memory, hash, or browser history object:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = new createBrowserHistory();
```

Import the plain `Router` from `react-router` and pass the history object as prop:

```
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { history } from '../path/to/custom/history';

...

<Router history={history}>
  ...
</Router>
```

Import and use `history` in the `getUser` action:

```
import { history } from '../path/to/custom/history';

...

const fetchUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosConfig.get('api/get-user');
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status == 401) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
}

export const getUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const user = await fetchUser();
    dispatch(actions.setUser(user));
  } catch {
    history.replace('/login');
  }
}
```

### Option 3

Pass the `history` object to the `getUser` action.

```
const fetchUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosConfig.get('api/get-user');
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status == 401) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
}

export const getUser = (history) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const user = await fetchUser();
    dispatch(actions.setUser(user));
  } catch {
    history.replace('/login');
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const history = useHistory();

...

getUser(history);

...

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getUser,
};
```

Comment: Option  2 replace url but not refresh component. I must press F5 to display login conmponent

Comment: @KaKi786 Did you ensure your `Router` is using the same history object by passing it the one you created?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. I changed only address to redirect from /login to main#/login (its correctly address)

Comment: @KaKi786 And this doesn't happen with either of the other two proposed solutions? When this happens I typically find that a dev is using more than one router where the inner router handles the route change and updates the URL in the address bar, but it's the outer router handling rendering the routes and so it's never notified of the route change (until a page reload when it can read the current path).

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work (not replace address) but I replace `dispatch(replace('/login'));` to `window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/main#/login") ` and it work like option 2 - replace addres, doesn't refresh component. When I use option 2, console return the error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

Comment: @KaKi786 Sorry for delay. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this navigation issue that we can inspect and debug live?